# How to accelerate a mysql query on vb6?

Tags: vb6

I have a table in MySQL with 6.000.000 records.

I am executing this query:

```
Cmd.CommandText = "select * from registro.cedcne where trim(cedula) = '" & Trim(txtCedula.Text) & "' limit 1"
```

The problem is the query is too slow. I get the result in 15 minutes.

When i execute the query using PhpMyAdmin i get the result less than 1 minute.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm using vb6 with ADO connection!

Comment: I guess the only optimisation that can be done toyour simple query is to limit the number of rows, by replacing the `*` with only columns that are needed.

Comment: Do you get all six million rows in one minute?

Comment: Thanks! The table it has just 5 fields and i need it all. One minute just for 1 row. Not all :-)

Comment: I'm not familiar with MySQL, but if you're using a client cursor and the admin tool is using a server cursor, that could explain the time difference - you're fetching all rows before being able to display the first one.  Try using a server cursor (if you're not currently, and which is the ADO default).  See the Recordset CursorLocation property, which would need to be set before you open the recordset.

Comment: I would try to avoid usage of the `trim`-function within the where-clause... I would say this is the cause for the performance penalty, because it must be calculated for each row... just my two cents.